# I need to make the same crops on multiple images in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I created 100's of images of bumblebees of the different morphs of each species. All in Photoshop Illustrator.

Now for an app I am building I need to separate a head, thorax, and abdomen into different .png or.jpg. I can't seem to find a way to make the same cuts on every single bee, without that it wont perfectly line up on my app and will look rather odd.

I can post some images or files if that would help explain it better. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: A key factor is whether the images are uniform (same size and cuts in exactly the same location), or the cuts are variable and located based on the image content.  Some sample images would be a big help (just post links to a public sharing site, like imgur.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can create actions in the action palette (`Window -> Actions`, it's commonly next to the history palette) which record a sequence of operations that you perform on a picture and then apply them to many files at once with batch processing. (`File > Automate > Batch`)